# Unable to save pbcopy to a new file without opening a text-editor

Tags: pbcopy

I tried the following code unsuccessfully

```
cat pbcopy >> newFile
```

**How can you save your clipboard to the file newFile without opening a text-editor?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `pbpaste >newFile`

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that it is that simple :)